# The BroadcastReceiver onReceive function runs two times

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

This is my source. I am using GCM push notification to send message to one app to another app. Message send first time onReceive () method called only one time when message, send second or more time the onReceive () method called two times how I can solve it.

```
BroadcastReceiver  mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if(newMessage.equals("request"))
        {
            System.out.println("Before Request Count"+reqcount);
                Userdetails();
        }
        else if(newMessage.equals("cancel"))
        {
            requestcanceled();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found the solution for that problem.

```
BroadcastReceiver  mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

context.unregisterReceiver(this); // this line I will added.
        if(newMessage.equals("request"))
        {
            System.out.println("Before Request Count"+reqcount);
                Userdetails();
        }
        else if(newMessage.equals("cancel"))
        {
            requestcanceled();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    }
```

After get the message just unregister the receiver and once again register tje receiver. Now its working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be a GCM bug. A lot of users experienced the same problem. Look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/EHZUTEJMeyw) for more detail

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and I can refer you are given link

Comment: The linked thread is over 2 years old. Not impossible, but a bit of a long shot.

Comment: May be wrong. If you check the code, and you are sure you are sending jsut one message...I can argue only a GCM bug.